# EF Core - null value in column "Id" of relation table violates not-null constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I seem to have this error when I insert something into my database table now. It is meant to auto-increment the id when adding a new item, and it has been working for months and I don't remember changing it so no idea why this is happening:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware:
> Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the
> request.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
> while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
> ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23502: null value in column "Id" of relation "VeganItems" violates not-null constraint
>
> DETAIL: Failing row contains (null, new item33, Aa, A, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> [{"Id":5,"IconCodePoint":63279,"Name":"Condiments"},{"Id":11,"Ic...,
> {}, GroceryItem, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
> null, 2022-03-13 14:29:40.995771, 2022-03-13 14:29:40.995771, null,
> KbnrgvYIt5UgTFohyyaSQ1GDIp02).    at
> Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.g__ReadMessageLong|213_0(NpgsqlConnector
> connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode,
> Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean
> async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean
> async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)    at
> Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject
> parameterObject)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection
> connection)   Exception data:
> Severity: ERROR
> SqlState: 23502
> MessageText: null value in column "Id" of relation "VeganItems" violates not-null constraint
> Detail: Failing row contains (null, new item33, Aa, A, 0, 0, 0, 0, [{"Id":5,"IconCodePoint":63279,"Name":"Condiments"},{"Id":11,"Ic...,
> {}, GroceryItem, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
> null, 2022-03-13 14:29:40.995771, 2022-03-13 14:29:40.995771, null,
> KbnrgvYIt5UgTFohyyaSQ1GDIp02).
> SchemaName: public
> TableName: VeganItems
> ColumnName: Id
> File: execMain.c
> Line: 1889
> Routine: ExecConstraints    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.Execute(IRelationalConnection
> connection)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1
> entries)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.<SaveChanges>b__104_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)    at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState
> state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean
> acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean
> acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()    at
> Vepo.DataContext.VepoContext.SaveChanges() in
> /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_back_end/Vepo.DataContext/VepoContext.cs:line
> 48    at
> Vepo.Data.VeganItemEstablishmentsRepository`3.Insert(TVeganItemEstablishment entity) in /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_back_end/Vepo.Data/Repositories/VeganItemEstablishments/VeganItemEstablishmentsRepository.cs:line 62    at Vepo.Services.VeganItemEstablishmentsService`4._InsertVeganItemEstablishment(TVeganItemEstablishmentDto
> entity) in
> /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_back_end/Vepo.Services/VeganItemEstablishments/VeganItemEstablishmentsService.cs:line
> 240    at
> Vepo.Services.VeganItemEstablishmentsService`4._handleNewVeganItem(TVeganItemEstablishmentDto veganItemEstablishment, ServiceResponse`1 _response) in
> /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_back_end/Vepo.Services/VeganItemEstablishments/VeganItemEstablishmentsService.cs:line
> 153    at
> Vepo.Services.VeganItemEstablishmentsService`4.AddOrUpdate(TVeganItemEstablishmentDto entity) in /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_back_end/Vepo.Services/VeganItemEstablishments/VeganItemEstablishmentsService.cs:line 104    at Vepo.Web.Controllers.VeganItemEstablishmentsController`4.PostVeganItemEstablishment(TVeganItemEstablishmentDto
> veganItemEstablishment) in
> /Users/benjaminfarquhar/dev/vepo_back_end/Vepo.Web/Controllers/VeganItemEstablishment/VeganItemEstablishmentsController.cs:line
> 34    at lambda_method321(Closure , Object )    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean
> isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State&
> next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker
> invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint
> endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context) dbug: 03/13/2022 14:29:41.271 CoreEventId.

The code is just:

protected DbSet veganItems;

```
public async override Task<TVeganItemEstablishment> Insert(
    TVeganItemEstablishment entity)
{
    var toReturnVeganItem = entity.VeganItem;
    var toReturnEstablishment = entity.Establishment;

    var result = veganItems.Add(entity.VeganItem);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

model builder:

```
    // Vegan Items

    modelBuilder.Entity<VeganItem>(veganItem =>
    {
        veganItem.HasIndex("CompanyName", "Name", "Discriminator").IsUnique();
        veganItem.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
        veganItem.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
        veganItem.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
            .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
        veganItem.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        veganItem.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
        veganItem.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
        veganItem.Property(e => e.Tags)
            .HasConversion(
                v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null),
                v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Option>>(v, (JsonSerializerOptions)null)
            );
    });
```

entity:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Nest;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Vepo.Application;

namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public class VeganItem : CreatedBySomeone
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
        [Required]
        public int IsVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
        [Required]
        public int RatingsCount { get; set; } = 0;
        [Required]
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public List<Option> Tags { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public List<String> Images { get; set; }
        public string Discriminator { get; set; }
    }
```

}

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using AutoMapper;

namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    [Serializable]
    public abstract class DomainEntity<TId> : DomainEntity
    {
        [Key]
        public TId Id { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public abstract class DomainEntity 
    {
        public System.DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class CreatedBySomeone : DomainEntity<int>
    {
        public string CreatedById { get; set; }
        public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedById { get; set; }
        public User UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Edit: it appears that Id is 0, not null:

[image]

Comment: It says you are trying to insert null value for id column. Can you try to manually set a value manually for the Id column for now, and try if the insert works?

Comment: @Zee It worked when I set  `entity.VeganItem.Id = 335;`
            `entity.Establishment.Id = 335;`
            `entity.Id = 335;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entity configuration does not autoincrement the Id.

Update VeganItem COnfiguration and Add this line in addition to AddKey.

```
    veganItem.Property(e => e.Id).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Comment: This is misleading. `int` type PKs by default are required and value generated on add.